# Simple routing to external URL

Tags: routing

I need to map:

```
https://my.domain/some-end-point
```

to

```
https://some.random/external/url
```

All the documentation and Q&A I found seems to require code. Doesn't Wordpress' CMS have a simple table I can edit? Is there perhaps a plug-in that does it?

Your help to get started would be much appreciated